# How to add 8 bits packed m256

Tags: assembly, avx

I have two m256 and i want to add byte by byte with AVX.

_mm256_add_epi8 This function does what I need but is AVX2.

Thanks

Comment: So you'll have to add two 128 bit halves instead.

Comment: Generally not worth using `__m256i` if you don't have AVX2 for 256-bit versions of integer SIMD instructions.

Comment: yes, but i don't find nothing with _m256i, if there is an option that work with _m256i i would know it

Comment: @mouadnaciri Not in AVX.  All the integer stuff was only added with AVX2.